# HTTP ERROR 503: can not access /. Reason Service Unavailable

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, url-pattern

My code is in github

```
https://github.com/shiblybcc/blog-aggregator
```

I have just created a spring framework project. This is my web.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Course Rating</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After I run my jetty server this works perfect and show the content of index.jsp file. But if I add following code in the web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I get the error

```
HTTP ERROR: 503    
Problem accessing /. Reason:    
    Service Unavailable
```

I am following a tutorial and they are doing the same. I don't understand what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check after adding : <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: This also doesn't work

Comment: What url you are hitting?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/index.htm  and http://localhost:8080

Comment: can you confirm that there were no errors (in the logs/console) during application deployment?

Comment: Yes. If required jars are present, it will not show any errors in logs as well as on console.

Comment: Yes I checked there are no errors in console and logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After whole day research I found the solution here
[Getting Error scanning file when running jetty 9 on java 8 using the maven jetty plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806946/getting-error-scanning-file-when-running-jetty-9-on-java-8-using-the-maven-jetty)

Also I updated jetty, maven and tomcat. My current pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After updating everything, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, understood, what is happening when you are calling localhost:8080/index.htm, servlet name "dispatcher" got executed and as there is no mapping for index.html exist, you will not be able to see the index.html page.

To make it work, you have to put little more efforts.

1). Put your index.html under WEB-INF folder.

2). Create Controller:

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexPageController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showIndexPage(ModelMap model) {
  return "index";
 }
}
```

3). Create mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml as below and put it under WEB-INF folder :

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
       <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
   </bean>

    </beans>
```

4). Edit your web.xml as:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <listener>
            <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
      </listener>
```

Comment: but I want to use annotations like Controller, RequestMapping

Comment: and now hit for : localhost:8080/index

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: What is the context of your application?. Mostly it's application name.

Comment: Yes I am getting an exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file IndexController.class. And from where can I check my application context?

Comment: When you deply application, server will show print the application context in logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76726/discussion-between-user1478137-and-arpit).